# Time Between 08:45:00 and 10:45:00

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a clock program and i'm troubled with something.

I have a label (TVGentTimeLabel) that gives me the current time.

What i want to do is when the time is between 08:45:00 and 10:45:00, my clock is red

When the time is between 10:45:01 and 23:59:59, than the clock is Green and else White

This is my code now:

```
Sub Timertijd_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timertijd.Tick

        TVGentTimeLabel.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss")

        If TVGentTimeLabel.Text = "08:45:00" Or TVGentTimeLabel.Text = "08:45:01" Then
            TVGentTimeLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf TVGentTimeLabel.Text = "10:45:01" Or TVGentTimeLabel.Text = "10:45:02" Then
            TVGentTimeLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf TVGentTimeLabel.Text = "00:00:01" Or TVGentTimeLabel.Text = "00:00:02" Then
            TVGentTimeLabel.ForeColor = Color.White
        End If

End Sub
```

The problem what i have now is when the program is started at a different time, it will be the color used as normal (in my case Black)

Please can someone help

Comment: You'd be better off evaluating using timespans than strings.  The code there assumes the tick will fire within a sec or two of what you want.

Comment: Yes, don't evaluate the time as a string. Store the value as a `DateTime` and compare that instead.

Comment: To me it sounds like the solution is already in your question: *"... and else White"* ... so changing your `ElseIf` to `Else` could solve your issue (apart from evaluating strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you currently have, this should work

```
   Private Sub Timertijd_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timertijd_Tick    

        Dim d As Date = TimeOfDay
        TVGentTimeLabel.Text = d.ToString("HH:mm:ss")

        If d >= #8:45:00 AM# And d <= #10:45:00 AM# Then
            TVGentTimeLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf d >= #10:45:01 AM# And d <= #11:59:59 PM# Then
            TVGentTimeLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green
        Else
            TVGentTimeLabel.ForeColor = Color.White
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: You could replace `#11:59:59 PM#' with `New Date(1, 1, 1, 23, 59, 59)`

Comment: I found it already :)   i used #20:00:00#  (example)  no need for the AM or PM

Answer (score 2):

The code is expecting the timer to tick exactly on one or 2 seconds and when it doesnt, the code doesnt have a way to handle it.  Since you are evaluating times, you should evaluate a `TimeSpan`, not a string:

```
    Dim ts = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay

    Dim tsA = New TimeSpan(8, 45, 0)    ' note: AM.  add 12 for PM traps
    Dim tsB = New TimeSpan(10, 45, 0)
    Dim tsC = New TimeSpan(12, 59, 59)

    If ts >= tsA AndAlso ts <= tsB Then
        ' red
    ElseIf ts > tsB AndAlso ts <= tsC Then
        'green
    Else
        'white
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting the colours of the label when they pass over a certain time. If you start it up, it will be a black colour until it passes over one of your `IF structures`. Try handling your `timeOfDay` as a date instead of a String.

```
Sub Timertijd_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timertijd.Tick

    If DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(8,45,0) AndAlso DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= New TimeSpan(10,45,0) Then
        TVGentTimeLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(10,45,0) AndAlso DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= New TimeSpan(23,59,59) Then
        TVGentTimeLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green
    ElseIf DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(0,0,0) AndAlso DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(8,44,59)
        TVGentTimeLabel.ForeColor = Color.White

End Sub
```